# How do I reassemble HTTP packets from Net::Pcap?

Tags: perl, http, network-programming, winpcap, libpcap

I am using the [`Net::Pcap` module](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-Pcap/) to capture packets with this filter:

```
dst $my_host and dst port 80
```

Inside the Net::Pcap event loop I use a callback function:

```
Net::Pcap::pcap_loop($pcap_t, -1, \my_callback, '')
```

where `my_callback` look like this:

```
my_callback {
    my ($user_data, $header, $packet) = @_;
    #   Strip ethernet IP and TCP
    my $ether_data = NetPacket::Ethernet::strip($packet);
    my $ip         = NetPacket::IP->decode($ether_data);
    my $tcp        = NetPacket::TCP->decode($ip->{'data'});
}
```

How can I assemble the HTTP packets into one packet and extract its header?

Comment: Well, if you're reading ethernet frames, you're going to have to have the reassembly code - either you write it or someone else does.

Comment: ok could you help how can i parse the http header and body ?

Answer (score 0):

try to use Sniffer::HTTP from CPAN